# How to adjust numbering of the next Word List Paragraph after hiding or unhiding the current List Paragraph using Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

My work needs me to hide and unhide texts within the word documents hundreds of times a day. So I've recorded a macro that will let me select a line / paragraph / list paragraph in the active Word document, and upon running the macro, that selection would be hidden away. This hidden text won't be showing up in the pages in the printer. Unhding the hidden text is pretty similar.

However, the problem I am unable to solve is adjust the numbering of the subsequent list paragraphs. Consider the scenario below:

[image]

If I were to hide the `List Paragraph b`, it would show as below:

[image]

After I print this out, the output would show as below:

[image]

As you can see, although the `List Paragraph b` is now hidden and not shown in the output, the subsequent lists are still showing as `List Paragraph c` and `List Paragraph d`,  which in this case should show as `List Paragraph b` and `List Paragraph c` instead, something like this:

[image]

How do I address the numbering of these subsequent List Paragraphs? I tried the `ListFormat.RemoveNumbers` method, but that isn't helping. It is instead removing the `List Paragraph b` entirely out of the current list, and also the subsequent List Paragraphs are not being auto adjusted. Same issue is with the `ListFormat.ListIndent` method - indents the hidden list paragraph, but still doesn't address the numbering of the subsequent List Paragraphs.

Also, the reverse process, i.e. unhiding the hidden text, should bring the numbering back in place.

I'm sure I'm missing something - could you please help point that out for me? Thank you!

---

EDIT: I was able to accomplish the auto-numbering after hiding using the `ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText` method. This is how the result is showing:

[image]

After this, the original second list item (i.e. `List Paragraph b`) is no more part of the list, and is converted to an ordinary paragraph that retains the indentation of the list items.

The challenge therefore is half done. How do I reverse this? What method will help me put this paragraph back into the list?

Comment: I assume the numbering issue is a concern only for printing? Why not remove all hidden text before printing and the automatic numbering will then flow correctly again?

Comment: The document would most likely be edited again multiple times and the hidden text maybe needed to be brought back again. These are sales documents, so they usually go through multiple iterations, therefore would be saved as sequential drafts.

Comment: If the numbering is attached to a paragraph style, which it should be, you can simply change the style of the paragraph before hiding it. Then just reapply the numbered style when you want to show the text again.

Comment: I will try that and let you know, thanks @Timothy Rylatt

Comment: See (Windows) http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html or (Mac) https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/06/outline-numbering-in-word-for-os-x/

Comment: @CharlesKenyon that reference seems to be a treasure, thank you so much! My understanding of these lists and list styles, paragraph styles isn't very advanced, so can't tell you how much it helped me grasp the concepts. Really appreciate it!

Comment: I am able to accomplish the first part of the task, i.e. detach a list paragraph from the original list (using `ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText`) before hiding that text, therefore the Word is able to handle the numbering automatically. How do I reverse this process? Select the second paragraph that is now no more part of the list, and then put it back up in the original list?